# How to decide if a function is a Fourier transform of a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

The function in question is
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
e^x \mbox{ if } x<0,\\
0 \mbox { if } x\geq0.
\end{cases}
$$
Is there an easy way to decide if there exists a function $f\in L^2(\mathbb R,\mathbb C)$ such that $\mathcal F(f)=g$? The inverse Fourier transform of $g(x)$ is 
$$
\frac 1{2\pi} \left( \frac 1{t^2+1}-i\frac t{t^2+1}\right).
$$

Comment: $g(x)$ is obviously in $L^{2}$ and even in Schwartz class. So the inverse Fourier transform of $g(x)$ should work. Don't worry!

Comment: Do you mean that from g(x) being in $L^2$ it follows that its inverse Fourier transform is also in $L^2$? Sorry if this is obvious, my knowledge on the Fourier transform is a bit rusty.

Comment: Yes, Fourier transform is an isometry on $L^{2}$. I believe you can prove this by hand.

Comment: See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlancherelsTheorem.html

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it know. Since $g(x)$ is a Schwartz function, I can use the inversion theorem, so $\mathcal F^{-1}(g)$ is just the flip of $\mathcal F(g)$, and both is in $L^2$ by the Plancherel theorem.

Comment: @Bombyxmori: The function $g$ is **not** Schwartz class, it is not even continuous. But it is an $L^2$ function and by Plancherel, the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}: L^2\to L^2$ is bijective, so this suffices.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Thinking about it twice I guess I confused $e^{-1/x}$ and $e^{-x}$. You are right it is not in Schwartz class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wrap it up we have
$$
\int|g|^{2}dx=\int^{0}_{-\infty}e^{2x}dx=\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}|^{0}_{-\infty}=\frac{1}{2}<\infty
$$
Therefore by Plancherels' theorem $\mathcal{G}g$ would work. In fact $g$ is also in $L^{1}$, so in fact lies in $L^{1}\cap L^{2}$, and Fourier transform is well defined, it needs no extension there. As PhoemueX pointed out the function is **not** in Schwartz class.

Comment: I consulted with the book "Classical Fourier Analysis" by G. Loukas. It turned out I was a little confused about the exact meaning of the inverse Fourier transform. I though it is just the inverse of the mapping $f\mapsto \mathcal F f$, but in this book it is defined as the flipping operator composed with $\mathcal F$. In some cases, this is indeed the inverse of $\mathcal F$. A sufficient condition is that $\mathcal Ff$ (or its flip) is also in $L^1$, which is true in this case.

Comment: @DávidKertész: With all respect I think you should consult a (slightly easier) book, I have the book with me and it is not a light read. If you have never seen this material before, you can begin with something easier (like big Rudin).

Comment: @Bombys mori: Thanks for the tip!